# What do numbers between parentheses in bash man pages mean: bash(1), ssh_config(5), sshd(8),

Tags: command-line, bash, manpage

Most of bash commands have an help manual which can be opened in the command line by using the command `man`:

```
man bash
man ssh_config
man sshd
```

On the first line of every man page for a command, we can see the name of the command immediately followed by a number within parentheses:

```
bash(1)
ssh_config(5)
sshd(8)
```

What does this number mean ? Does any of you know a page which would list all possible values of numbers which can appear between these parentheses and their meaning ?

Comment: I think you will find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-parentheses-shown-after-unix-command-names-mean).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sections of the man pages

> This page describes the conventions that should be employed when
>          writing man pages for the Linux man-pages project, which documents
>          the user-space API provided by the Linux kernel and the GNU C
>          library.  The project thus provides most of the pages in Section 2,
>          as well as many of the pages that appear in Sections 3, 4, 5, and 7
>          of the man pages on a Linux system.  The conventions described on
>          this page may also be useful for authors writing man pages for other
>          projects.
>
> Sections of the manual pages
>          The manual Sections are traditionally defined as follows:
>
> ```
>    1 User commands (Programs)
>              Those commands that can be executed by the user from within
>              a shell.
>
>    2 System calls
>              Those functions which wrap operations performed by the
>              kernel.
>
>    3 Library calls
>              All library functions excluding the system call wrappers
>              (Most of the libc functions).
>
>    4 Special files (devices)
>              Files found in /dev which allow to access to devices
>              through the kernel.
>
>    5 File formats and configuration files
>              Describes various human-readable file formats and
>              configuration files.
>
>    6 Games   Games and funny little programs available on the system.
>
>    7 Overview, conventions, and miscellaneous
>              Overviews or descriptions of various topics, conventions
>              and protocols, character set standards, the standard
>              filesystem layout, and miscellaneous other things.
>
>    8 System management commands
>              Commands like mount(8), many of which only root can
>              execute.
> ```

See man man for details =)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/man.1.html