# Can anybody explain output of getent passwd command?

Tags: users, user-management

`mymac` is my personal user account on juggernaut machine

```
mymac:x:1000:1000:juggernaut,,,:/home/mymac:/bin/bash
```

What does that x, 1000 , 1000 mean? And the commas that follow?

In analogy, also explain:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [`man 5 passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/passwd.5):

```
/etc/passwd contains one line for each user account, with seven fields
delimited by colons (“:”). These fields are:

·   login name
·   optional encrypted password
·   numerical user ID
·   numerical group ID
·   user name or comment field
·   user home directory
·   optional user command interpreter
```

The `x` would be the optional encrypted password, about which the manpage further goes on to say:

```
The encrypted password field may be blank, in which case no password is
required to authenticate as the specified login name. However, some
applications which read the /etc/passwd file may decide not to permit
any access at all if the password field is blank. If the password field
is a lower-case “x”, then the encrypted password is actually stored in
the shadow(5) file instead; there must be a corresponding line in the
/etc/shadow file, or else the user account is invalid. If the password
field is any other string, then it will be treated as an encrypted
password, as specified by crypt(3).
```

The commas are separating [the GECOS fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field):

> The typical format for the GECOS field is a comma-delimited list with
>   this order:
>
> 1. User's full name (or application name, if the account is for a program)
> 2. Building and room number or contact person
> 3. Office telephone number
> 4. Any other contact information (pager number, fax, etc.)

So:

```
mymac:x:1000:1000:juggernaut,,,:/home/mymac:/bin/bash
|     |  |    |    |             |             |
|     |  |    |    |             |             Login shell
|     |  |    |    |             Home directory
|     |  |    |    GECOS fields (full name, etc.)
|     |  |    Primary Group id
|     |  User ID
|     Encrypted password indicator
Username
```

Comment: one more thing... can u also explain the entries in shadow file?

Comment: @juggernaut1996 See [`man 5 shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shadow.5).

Comment: @juggernaut1996 So, should I copy paste another manpage for you? The explanations in [`man 5 shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shadow.5) are pretty clear.

Comment: Why "man 5 passwd" and not "man passwd"? I did "man man" but I didn't get it.

Comment: @Noumenon https://askubuntu.com/q/647051/158442