# Output of getent group

Tags: command-line, server, users, groups

Similar to [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725120/can-anybody-explain-output-of-getent-passwd-command), but different result set, can anyone help me with the output of `getent group`?

It's something like this:

```
groupname:x:0:
```

just not sure what the `x:0:` signifies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
getent group <group_name>
```

queries the `/etc/group` file and gets the entry for the mentioned group from the file.

The output format is:

```
group:password:GID:user(s)
```

- `group` is the group's name
- `password` is the encrypted group password, empty field signifies no password, `x` bit signifies the password is in the file `/etc/gshadow`
- `GID` is the Group ID
- `user(s)` is the list of users member of this group, empty means this group has no member.

Now, if you check the `/etc/gshadow` file you will see that the group password is locked (`!` or `*`) in the password field, thats because the group password is not used. It's considered a security risk to have all members of the group share the same password. (At least i have never come across any implementation of `gshadow`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This confirms what I thought, and expands on the assumptions that I made.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not complete. `getent` also reads SSSD info to get LDAP group which is not listed in `/etc/group`. `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` and check the `group` line to see what group info source you have.

```bsh
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd sss
group:          compat systemd sss
shadow:         compat sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        files sss
```