# Man files, too many folders

Tags: manpage

I wanted to know about a terminal program, so I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and

```
man prog_name
```

and nothing was found. So I want to add a new file to man, containing instructions I've found online, and I've started looking for it's directory and I've see there are 5 man directories in my

```
/usr/share/man$ ls

ar   ca@valencia  en_GB  fr_CA         hu  ko    man6  ne     ro   sv     zh_CN
ast  ce           eo     fr.ISO8859-1  hy  ku    man7  nl     ru   ta        zh_HK
az   cs           es     fr.UTF-8      ia  lt    man8  nn     se   te  zh_TW
be   cy           et     fy            id  lv    mhr   oc     shn  th
bg   da           eu     gd            io  man1  ml    pa     si   tr
bn   de           fa     gl            it  man2  mr    pl     sk   ug
bo   el           fi     he            ja  man3  ms    ps     sl   uk
bs   en_AU        fo     hi            kk  man4  my    pt     sq   uz
ca   en_CA        fr     hr            km  man5  nb    pt_BR  sr   vi
```

why are there 5 different directories for man and where should I place my file??

edit: the questions are completely different

Comment: What program are you referring to, specifically? sometimes there's a separate documentation package that you can install. I really don't recommend adding random files to /usr/share/man (if you must, then use somewhere like /usr/local/share/man). As to why there are many subdirectories, it's related to [What do numbers between parentheses in bash man pages mean: bash(1), ssh_config(5), sshd(8)](https://askubuntu.com/a/647055/178692)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do numbers between parentheses in bash man pages mean: bash(1), ssh\_config(5), sshd(8),](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647051/what-do-numbers-between-parentheses-in-bash-man-pages-mean-bash1-ssh-config)

Comment: Sometimes, the documentation is in a separate package from the main package. Using `apt search | grep program_name` is a way to see if that is the case. Also, `info` may provide more complete documentation than `man` for some programs.